AngularCompilerPlugin - TypeError: Cannot read property 'thisCompilation' of undefined
I am trying to get away from angular2-template-loader and awesome-typescript-loader and use @ngtools/webpack as a alternate to fix security vulnerabilities identified for the subcomponents like loader-utils.
When I replace angular2-template-loader and awesome-typescript-loader with @ngtools/webpack which requires AngularCompilerPlugin configured in the webpack, I run in to the following error.
C:\......\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:348
                        throw err;
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'thisCompilation' of undefined
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.apply (C:\......\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:416:24)
    at Compiler.apply (C:\...\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:375:16)
    at webpack (C:\...\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:33:19)
    at processOptions (C:\...\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:335:15)
    at C:\...\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:397:2
    at Object.Yargs.self.parse (C:\...\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:533:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:152:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:4

my Webpack.config.js file has definition AngularCompilerPlugin plugins as shown below:
 var plugins =  [
    new AngularCompilerPlugin(
        {
            tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json'
        }
    ),
    new TransferWebpackPlugin([
        {from: paths.pdf, to: path.join('assets/pdfjs')}
    ]
    )];
    
    

I am just passing the required  tsConfigPath.
Here is my dependencies from Package.json:
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "=5.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "=5.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "=5.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "=5.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "=5.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "=5.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "=5.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "=5.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "=5.2.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "=1.0.1",
    "@practice/web-core": "=2019.3.4-1",
    "animate.css": "=3.7.0",
    "core-js": "=2.5.3",
    "karma": "^6.4.2",
    "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "=0.2.29",
    "ng2-tree": "=2.0.0-rc.11",
    "ngx-cookie": "=2.0.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "=5.5.6",
    "uuid": "=3.2.1",
    "zone.js": "=0.8.20"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^7.3.10",
    "@practice/coding-standards": "=1.0.8",
    "@practice/token-replace": "=1.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "=2.8.6",
    "@types/node": "=9.4.6",
    "@types/node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "@types/uuid": "=3.4.3",
    "ajv": "=6.2.1",
    "clean-css-cli": "=4.1.10",
    "cpy-cli": "=1.0.1",
    "css-loader": "=0.28.10",
    "eslint": "=4.18.1",
    "htmlhint": "=0.9.13",
    "jasmine": "=3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "=2.99.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "=1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "=0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "=1.2.0",
    "karma-typescript": "=3.0.12",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "npm-watch": "^0.9.0",
    "raw-loader": "=0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "=2.6.2",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "sass-lint": "=1.12.1",
    "sass-loader": "=7.0.3",
    "to-string-loader": "=1.1.5",
    "transfer-webpack-plugin": "=0.1.4",
    "tslint": "=5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "uglify-js": "=3.3.12",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  }

